# Getting WARN While Installing Cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I encountered this warning while installing Cordova

```sh
C:\Users\shams>npm install -g cordova
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
C:\Users\shams\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\shams\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
+ cordova@9.0.0
added 432 packages from 355 contributors in 30.426s
```

[image: WARN While Installing Cordova]

Comment: try npm install -g cordova@latest

Comment: @Eric Same warn shows again

Comment: what  is the question?